# How to find a string from a column

Tags: r

I have a df as below

df:

```
Name               |Code
-------------------+-----
aman               |abc
akash              |bcd
rudra              |cde
Tushar             |def
Kartik             |efg
aman,akash         |fgh
akash,rudra        |ghi
akash,rudra,aman   |ijk
aman,Tushar        |jkl
Kartik,Tushar      |klm
rudra,Kartik,akash |lmn
```

i want to search code for combo "aman,akash,rudra" and "Tushar,aman" to get result as "ijk" and "jkl"....

let me know if there is some way to achieve this.

Comment: Your approach is not good, because you are trying to search comma-separated data in a single column.  This renders much of the power R has useless.  Instead, normalize your data by placing each name in a separate row.

Comment: Maybe `library(tidyverse); df %>% mutate(id = row_number()) %>% separate_rows(Name) %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(all(c('aman', 'akash', 'rudra') %in% Name) | all(c('Tushar', 'aman') %in% Name))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `%in%`

```
df$Code[df$Name %in% c("akash,rudra,aman", "aman,Tushar")]
#[1] "ijk" "jkl"
```

---

If the order is flexible

```
df$Code[sapply(strsplit(df$Name, ","), function(x) 
   all(c("akash", "rudra", "aman") %in% x) | all(c("aman", "Tushar") %in% x))]
#[1] "ijk" "jkl"
```

Comment: iu have changed the order of input data to c("akash,rudra,aman", "aman,Tushar")... i want a code which can automatically check the table for all combination of strings

Comment: @DavidArenburg  In that case, the expected output will be different from the one showed in the OP's post.  For example `aman` matches the first element, so `abc` would be included

Comment: @DavidArenburg  That is why in the second case, I did the `strsplit`

Comment: thanks... it worked for my set of data. Can you help in case  i have a data frame of strings which i need to search

Comment: @aman Sure, i can help you.  Please do post as a separate question

Answer (score 0):

It can be used regular expressions in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Name` REGEXP '/(aman,akash,rudra)|(Tushar,aman)/';
```

P.S. It's just as an example... not the final solution

Comment: REGEXP function is not found

Comment: @FieryCat Are you aware to the tags on that question? This is an R question FYI.